# Alignment in dynamic table rows

Tags: html, css

The problem is that I have table, where 2 column ROWS are filled dynamically.

So for each row there are n amount of extra rows for last columns. 
Column #2 has only numbers, but column #3 has text.

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
       <p>5</p>
       <p>2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
       <p>text</p>
       <p>text</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now the problem is that if 3rd column has long text (goes onto next line), then column #2 and column #3 loses alignment. What I need is to have multiple rows within  tags and paragraph tags to be vertically aligned to each other.

JS fiddle to describe the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/a85ZK/3/

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: The way that number "10" in fiddle would be on same the same line as "text" (like "5" is compared to "too long"

Comment: td {vertical-align:middle;} it is usually the defaut value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of your `table` needs to be set with 2 rows.

The first cell of first row to be spanned over the two rows with the attribute `rowspan="2"` **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a85ZK/4/)**

```
<table border="1" style="text-align: center;">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>count</th>
            <th width="50">position</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;" rowspan="2">1</td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                5
            </td>
            <td>
                too long text that stretches column
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                10
            </td>
            <td>
                text
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You focused on a problem on a wrong angle. The problem is between column #2 and column #3 not column #1 and column #2 :)

Comment: is this you look for ? http://jsfiddle.net/a85ZK/2/ cause in your fiddle , every tds are vertical-aligned and width of table is set to 50px. I do not follow anymore, unless those attributes in HTML table are not meant to be ?   . else do you mean, one simgle line per row ? or is this it : http://jsfiddle.net/a85ZK/4/ ?

Comment: Fixed jsfiddle. Problem is that "10" should be on the same row as last row's "text"

    "5" - "too long text that stretches column"
    "10" - "text" (last row)

Comment: @R.P okay, so you need 2 rows : http://jsfiddle.net/a85ZK/4/ . it needs structure to be updated

Comment: Sorry for late response, but Your last comment is exactly what i was looking for. Could You please remove <p> as well and css so it would fit question perfectly, after that I will accept Your answer.

Comment: @R.P , okay, i did. Hope explanation is understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

> you need to make class or id for the td  i think you might have the same div for each table row
>   that's why its causing you a problem.

```
<tr>
<td class="something"></td>
<p>somthing</p>
<td class="something"></td>
<p></p>
<td class="somthing"></td>
</tr>
```